# How to uniquely identify dynamically loaded controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form which creates controls dynamically and adds event handlers by itself (already coded that part). As for now, I have a hidden table with the object list which loops through the controls and finds it by name (using the Me.Controls collection). How ever, does anyone knows if a dynamically created control may have a special unique code ?

I believe that there is one but I don`t know it.....

any help would be greatly appriciated !

Doron.

Comment: What kind of a code are you looking for? In particular, what advantage should that code have over searching for a name?<br/>Also, I am not sure what you mean by *using the Me.Controls collection* - either, you find the controls in a table or in the `Me.Controls` collection.

Comment: I believe this is true for ASP.NET controls, but as the answers below indicate, not exactly so for WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

All controls have a `Handle` property which should be unique.  If you want more control over it (pardon the pun), you could set the `Tag` property of each control to a new GUID.  Then you could use that to uniquely identify them.

```
Dim dynamicControl As Control = ...
dynamicControl.Tag = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

What I don't understand, though, is why the values you are using for the `Name` property aren't already unique, because that would be the normal way to uniquely identify controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom controls then this is fairly easy to accomplish, if you are trying to do it with built in controls(labels, buttons, text boxes etc.) then it is a little trickier.

I answered a question like this for someone else doing something similar but using custom controls [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321225/vb-net-visual-studio-2010-incrementing-control-names-at-runtime/10321569#10321569).

For built in controls you can do a couple things. You can set the value in the Tag property like Steven Doggart has mentioned, or you can create your own custom class that inherits the control you want to use and add any identifying properties you want to it.

Once you select a method of storing an ID you can actually use LINQ on the `Me.Controls` collection and get out all controls by type/Tag/whatever. Having said that, I do not think there is an easily accessible/predictable unique identifier given to each individual control on a form. If you want to reference a particular control specifically then you need to give it an identifier you will be able to assume at run time, otherwise no one, including you, will know exactly which control you are supposed to be working with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're setting the Control.Name property when you create it?
You may be after the Control.Handle?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' create controls
        For i As Integer = 1 To 5
            Dim t As New TextBox
            t.Name = "TextBox" & i
            Me.Controls.Add(t)
        Next

        ' list controls
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
            Debug.Print(c.Name & " has handle " & c.Handle.ToString)
        Next

        ' check fopr existence of controls
        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
            If Me.Controls.ContainsKey("TextBox" & i) Then
                Debug.Print("TextBox" & i & " exists")
            Else
                Debug.Print("TextBox" & i & " doesn't exist")
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

This program creates the following output:

```
TextBox1 has handle 2361834
TextBox2 has handle 3739570
TextBox3 has handle 8130020
TextBox4 has handle 5048814
TextBox5 has handle 6425036
TextBox0 doesn't exist
TextBox1 exists
TextBox2 exists
TextBox3 exists
TextBox4 exists
TextBox5 exists
TextBox6 doesn't exist
TextBox7 doesn't exist
```